# Converting files from big endian Fortran unformatted with 64-bit floating point to a data file

Tags: endianness

Hello I am new to this so pardon my general lack of understanding about most things :]

I am trying to read in grid files to a CFD code written by a long since gone student in the lab I work in. The files are big endian Fortran unformatted with 64-bit floating point.  I need some sort of text or data file that I can read on the screen so I can appropriately modify the portion of the code reading in the file.  After a few google searches I am at a loss (I am by no means a computer science person) although I think I understand generally what big endian is and what an unformatted file is.  How can I convert these files to something readable?  Thanks for any help that can be offered!!  Also if it helps the link to the grid files I need to convert is

ftp://cmb24.larc.nasa.gov/outgoing/DPW5/unstructured_grids.REV01/

Thanks again!!

--M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could play around with python and numpy:

```
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np

file = "L1.T.rev01.p3d.hex.r8.ugrid"
n=8
dt = np.dtype([('field0','>f8'), ('field1', '>f8'), ('field2', '>f8')])
ndt = len(dt)
data = np.fromfile(file, dt, count=n) #omit count= to read all records

for row in data:
    print(row)
    #print(row['field0'])
```

which printed the following to screen:

```
(5.9416208318e-313, 2.0743e-319, 0.0)
(3.15696e-318, 5.94342273776e-313, 260.16056)
(0.0, 118.46084, 272.1421)
(0.0, 115.94573, 284.80264)
(0.0, 113.49254, 298.1431)
(0.0, 111.13511, 312.15776)
(0.0, 108.90879, 326.83354)
(0.0, 106.84945, 342.14944)
```

I'm not sure how to handle headers but [efficient-way-to-create-numpy-arrays-from-binary-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569563/efficient-way-to-create-numpy-arrays-from-binary-files#answer-7576420) might help.
For the big-endian, small-endian and other data types in numpy see [Data type objects](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's probably this format:

http://www.simcenter.msstate.edu/docs/ug_io/file_formats.html

...and that you may be able to open it with some piece of software from here?:

http://www.laerdal.com/us/SimCenter

Is this along the right lines? Are your files about simulation, and do the files contain 3D scene data (this is just my guess based on initial glance)?

...and if so, I would try to go through the tech support channels, if possible - perhaps someone there will know a lot more about it:

http://www.laerdal.com/us/doc/417/Technical-Support