# Is there a way to increment numpy array that isn't slow?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a script that accumulates (counts) bytes contained in two files. Bytes are C-like `unsigned char` integer values between 0 and 255.

The goal of this accumulator script is to count the joint counts or frequencies of bytes in those two files. Possibly to extend this out to multiple files/dimensions.

The two files are the same size, but they are very large, on the order of 6 TB or so.

I am using `numpy.uint64` values, as I am getting overflow problems using Python's `int` type.

I have a 1D accumulator array that is `255**2` in length, in order to store joint counts.

I calculate the offset from a row-by-column -to- array offset calculation, so as to increment the joint frequency at the right index. I walk through both files in chunks of bytes (`n_bytes`), unpack them, and increment the frequency counter.

Here's a rough sketch of the code:

```
import numpy
import ctypes
import struct

buckets_per_signal_type = 2**(ctypes.c_ubyte(1).value * 8)
total_buckets = buckets_per_signal_type**2
buckets = numpy.zeros((total_buckets,), dtype=numpy.uint64)

# open file handles to two files (omitted for brevity...)

# buffer size that is known ahead of time to be a divisible 
# unit of the original files 
# (for example, here, reading in 2.4e6 bytes per loop iteration)
n_bytes = 2400000

total_bytes = 0L

# format used to unpack bytes
struct_format = "=%dB" % (n_bytes)

while True:    
    # read in n_bytes chunk from each file
    first_file_bytes = first_file_handle.read(n_bytes)
    second_file_bytes = second_file_handle.read(n_bytes)

    # break if both file handles have nothing left to read
    if len(first_file_bytes) == 0 and len(second_file_bytes) == 0:
        break

    # unpack actual bytes
    first_bytes_unpacked = struct.unpack(struct_format, first_file_bytes)
    second_bytes_unpacked = struct.unpack(struct_format, second_file_bytes)

    for index in range(0, n_bytes):
        first_byte = first_bytes_unpacked[index]
        second_byte = second_bytes_unpacked[index]
        offset = first_byte * buckets_per_signal_type + second_byte
        buckets[offset] += 1

    total_bytes += n_bytes
    # repeat until both file handles are both EOF

# print out joint frequency (omitted)
```

Compared with the version where I used `int`, this is incredibly slow, on an order of magnitude slower. The original job completed (incorrectly, due to overflow) in about 8 hours, and this numpy-based version had to be quit early as it will appear to take about 12-14 days to finish.

Either numpy is incredibly slow at this basic task, or I'm not doing an accumulator with numpy in a way that is Python-like. I suspect the latter, which is why I'm asking SO for help.

I read about `numpy.add.at`, but the unpacked byte arrays I would add to the `buckets` array do not have offset values that translate naturally to the "shape" of the `buckets` array.

Is there a way to store and increment an array of (long) integers, that does not overflow, and which is reasonably performant?

I could rewrite this in C, I guess, but am hoping there is something in numpy I am overlooking that will solve this quickly. Thanks for your advice.

**Update**

I had older versions of numpy and scipy that did not support `numpy.add.at`. So that was another issue to look into.

I'll try the following and see how that goes:

```
first_byte_arr = np.array(first_bytes_unpacked)                                                                                 
second_byte_arr = np.array(second_bytes_unpacked)                                                                                
offsets = first_byte_arr * buckets_per_signal_type + second_byte_arr                                                               
np.add.at(buckets, offsets, 1L)
```

Hopefully it runs a little faster!

**Update II**

Using `np.add.at` and `np.array`, this job will take roughly 12 days to complete. I'm going to give up on `numpy` for now and go back to reading raw bytes with C, where the runtimes are a bit more reasonable. Thanks all for your advice!

Comment: "I read about `numpy.add.at`, but the unpacked byte arrays I would add to the `buckets` array do not have offset values that translate naturally to the "shape" of the `buckets` array." - could you force that using, say, `np.digitize`?  Unfortunately I can't follow the things you are doing with `struct` well enough to give a good answer about the `numpy`

Comment: `struct` is used here to quickly generate an array of integers between 0 and 255 from each byte. I have one byte from the first file that maps to byte or integer A and one byte from the second file that maps to byte/integer B. I count how many times I see A and B together. 

I don't seem to get enough from the `numpy.digitize` documentation to see how it applies here, but I'll review it some more and see if it helps. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: So the only difference between this and the `int` version is the `dtype` of `buckets`?  `add.at` is only useful if you are indexing duplicate elements in one call.  In your code `offset` is just a scalar, right?

Comment: The original array is a zeroed list of `int` defined like so: `buckets = [0] * total_buckets`. I was aiming for something Python-y before going to a third-party library.

Comment: Why not use a 2d `(256, 256)` `buckets` and do `buckets[first, second] +=1`?  Or even something like `np.add.at(buckets, (first, second) 1)`

Comment: in any case, a [mcve] that removes dependencies other than `numpy` would be helpful to get a good answer, as it's probably a simple vectorization problem.  And we've got some vectorization wizards around here that can help if they can understand the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid a minimal, complete and verifiable example may be beyond the scope of this question. It's just too much code to copy and paste. I was hoping the pseudocode would be clear to people familiar with those libraries. Thanks for the help, in any case. I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Without trying to follow all the file read and `struct` code, it looks like you are adding `1`  to an assortment of slots in the `buckets` array.  That part shouldn't be taking days.

But to get an idea of how the `dtype` of `buckets` affects that step, I'll test adding 1 to a random assortment of indices.

```
In [57]: idx = np.random.randint(0,255**2,10000)
In [58]: %%timeit buckets = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.int64)
    ...: for i in idx:
    ...:    buckets[i] += 1
    ...: 
9.38 ms ± 39.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
In [59]: %%timeit buckets = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.uint64)
    ...: for i in idx:
    ...:    buckets[i] += 1
    ...: 
71.7 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

`uint64` is about 8x slower.

If there weren't duplicates, we could just do `buckets[idx] += 1`.  But allowing for duplicates we have to use `add.at`:

```
In [60]: %%timeit buckets = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.int64)
    ...: np.add.at(buckets, idx, 1)
    ...: 
1.6 ms ± 348 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [61]: %%timeit buckets = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.uint64)
    ...: np.add.at(buckets, idx, 1)
    ...: 
1.62 ms ± 15.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Interesting that dtype `uint64` does not affect the timing in this case.

You mention in comments that you tried a list accumulator.  I assume like this:

```
In [62]: %%timeit buckets = [0]*(255**2)
    ...: for i in idx:
    ...:    buckets[i] += 1
    ...: 
3.59 ms ± 44.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

That's faster than the iterative version of the array.  In general iteration on arrays is slower than on lists.  It's the 'whole-array' operations that are faster, such as `add.at`.

---

To verify that `add.at` is the correct substitute for iteration, compare

```
In [63]: buckets0 = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.int64)
In [64]: for i in idx: buckets0[i] += 1

In [66]: buckets01 = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.int64)
In [67]: np.add.at(buckets01, idx, 1)
In [68]: np.allclose(buckets0, buckets01)
Out[68]: True

In [69]: buckets02 = np.zeros(255**2, dtype=np.int64)
In [70]: buckets02[idx] += 1
In [71]: np.allclose(buckets0, buckets02)
Out[71]: False

In [75]: bucketslist = [0]*(255**2)
In [76]: for i in idx: bucketslist[i] += 1
In [77]: np.allclose(buckets0, bucketslist)
Out[77]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `numpy` has its own file I/O method in [`fromfile`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html) which you'd probably be better off using if you want the output in a `numpy` array. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569563/efficient-way-to-create-numpy-arrays-from-binary-files))
2. Probably better to use the `array` structure given by `numpy` to make your `buckets` a 2d array:

   ```
   buckets_per_signal_type = 2**(ctypes.c_ubyte(1).value * 8)
   buckets = numpy.zeros((buckets_per_signal_type, buckets_per_signal_type), dtype=numpy.uint64)
   ```

   And then just use `np.add.at` to increment the bins

   ```
   # define record_type to match your data
   while True
       data_1 = np.fromfile(first_file_handle, dtype=record_dtype, count=nbytes)
       data_2 = np.fromfile(second_file_handle, dtype=record_dtype, count=nbytes)
       s = np.minimum(data_1.size, data_2.size)
       if s == 0:
           break
       np.add.at(buckets, [data_1[:s], data_2[:s]], 1)
   ```