# Python 3.5 - Convert bytes object to 16bit hex string (b'\x07\x89' -> '0x0789')

Tags: python, python-3.x, hex, byte

some device returns data (hex bytes) in the form of

```
data = b'\x07\x89\x00\x00\x12\x34'
```

How can I convert this to something in the form of the following?

```
['0x0789', '0x0000', '0x1234']
```

I already tried compositions of hexlify. I am using Python 3.5.

Comment: I think your question title is a little misleading. What you actually want is to convert \xAB\xCD to \xABCD for a sequence of bytes and get the string representation. Can you come up with a better title?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take groups of two from your `bytes` object. Multiply the first value from each group with 16**2. Add the two values. Use `hex` on the result to convert it to its string representation.

```
>>> [hex(data[i]*16**2 + data[i+1]) for i in range(0,len(data),2)]
['0x789', '0x0', '0x1234']
```

I assume that you don't need your strings padded with useless zeros for now.

Comment: also: `'0x%02X%02X' % tuple(data[i:i+2])`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I don't get your comment, can you elaborate?

Comment: `['0x%02X%02X' % tuple(data[i:i+2]) for i in range(0,len(data),2)]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) module; it has `unpack` function which allows to specify the chunk size size (byte, 2-byte, 4-bytes) and endianess in the data. If what you have is big-endian half-word sized data chunks, then the right format key is ">H".

To parse all data at one, add count in the format specifier: for example ">3H" for you input array. You can also write the number of fields dynamically.

Full example:

```
import struct
data = b'\x07\x89\x00\x00\x12\x34'
d = struct.unpack(">{}H".format(len(data) // 2), data) # extract fields
result = [hex(x) for x in d] # convert to strings
```

Comment: @PatrickBateman My mistake, should have noticed this  is Python 3. You should also tag the question with `python-3` tag. The difference is that `/` is always floating-point division in Py3, should use `//` instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps:

1. Chunk the input bytestring into 2-byte sequences
2. Display the sequences as hex literals.

You could [use `array` module from stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html):

```
import sys
from array import array

a = array('H', data)
if sys.byteorder != 'big':
    a.byteswap() # use big-endian order
result = ['0x%04X' % i for i in a]
# -> ['0x0789', '0x0000', '0x1234']
```

It is efficient, [especially if you need to read data from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805696/4279).